# Remove columns in gridview

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

How do you remove this:

[image]

Comment: which js or language you are using.

Comment: this is a Windows Forms DataGridView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* that is a Windows Forms DataGridView in .Net, then you can hide that column by setting RowHeadersVisible to false, either in the Properties window or at runtime.